# Majority Function in C++ using 3 uint8_t

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

```
uint8_t a = 0x01; //00000001
uint8_t b = 0xff; //11111111
uint8_t c = 0xf0; //11110000

maj(a,b,c) = 0xf1; //11110001
```

I'm unsure how to access and compare each bit so I can come to the result?

Comment: What exactly does `maj` do?

Comment: The binary value in the comment doesn't match the hex value of the result of your function. Is it `0xf0` or `0xf1`?

Comment: maj outputs the majority, ie 0,0,1 = 0; 1,1,1 = 1l 1,0,1 = 1 and so on

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
result = (a & b) | (b & c) | (c & a);
```

Comment: Thanks, this jogged my memory as to how it's compared.

Comment: Finally, got an idea about the semantics of `maj` from the algo.

Answer (score 7):

@Henrik has already offered a nice straightforward solution which requires 5 operations. FWIW if efficiency is a concern you can reduce this to 4 operations:

```
result = (a & (b | c)) | (b & c);
```